How do I put Apache Superset as an app in a Django project?
How do I put Apache Superset as an app in a Dango project?
I tried to install the tool using Docker, but I want to use the Superset tool with the Django project so that it becomes an application among the applications in the Django project.

What makes you think that it can be a Django app?

Apache Superset is somewhat of a big application of its own. Also it uses Flask and various different Flask related libraries instead of Django. You're probably better off keeping the two as separate applications and trying to get them to work together w.r.t. user experience.

Integrating Apache Superset into a Django project as an application can be complex because Superset is a standalone application with its own web server. However, you can set up reverse proxying like nginx to make it appear as part of your Django project.

It's actually a bit more complicated than that, Apache Superset has some relative URLs hardcoded (from what I remember from 1-2 years ago), which means if you want to serve it on a specific URL path you'll have to modify all of those so that it doesn't break.
